# SpringBoot Component autowired from Test class null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a test class that `@Autowired`s two different classes in. One of them is @Service and the other is @RestController.

When I use the @Service one, it works fine.

When I use the @RestController one, it throws a NullPointerException.

Is there some reason why it can't wire up the Controller? I figured maybe it has something with creating the web context but I also tried adding the SpringBootTest with a webEnvironment pointing at MOCK (and others) to see if that would get it to kick in.

I also kicked around the MockMvc stuff but I am not exactly sure how that's supposed to work.

Is there some way to easily call one of these controllers to do a full integration test case?

```
@Autowired
private ThingService tservice;

@Autowired
private ThingController tconn;

@Test
public void testRunThing() {
    Thing t = new Thing(1, "Test");
    tservice.configureThing(t);
    Thing t2 = new Thing(1, "Second thing");
    tconn.getThing(t2);

    t3 = tservice.findThing(1);
    assertEqual(t3.getValue(), "Second thing");
}
```

The `tservice` function does a little bit including ultimately persisting to a DB (in this case H2 which it, in turn has autowired in through a repository).

The `tconn` function handles an update as if it was sent to the rest endpoint (in this case, it would update the "thing" with ID of 1 to the new string value)

the null pointer shows up on the `tconn.getThing()` call.

Comment: Can you please add the test class to the question?

Comment: @Boris I added a bit of a cut down example

Comment: Ok, and what are the annotations at the class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of MockMvc usage:
Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LoginControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

Simple test

```
        @Test
        public void loginOk() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/login").param("username", "name")
                    .param("password", "1111" )).andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
        }
```

If you want just to check that it's an object in response you can use

```
 .andExpect(content().json("{}"));
```

empty array in response

```
 .andExpect(content().json("[]"));
```

array with two objects

```
.andExpect(content().json("[{}, {}]"));
```

if you want the exact result you can get it as a json string and then parse it.

```
 MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/login").param("username", "name")
                    .param("password", "1111" )).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andReturn();
String resultJsonString = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

You need a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This just causes an exception on the `this.mockMvc.perform` line `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException` -- This might be unrelated...

Comment: It shows that the test is working and you got NullPointerException somewhere in your app when you make a request to the rest enpoint you are testing. If you can provide the exact code of your controller method(with all annotations) i'll be able to give you the exact tescase code for this endpoint to be sure that the testcase is writen properly.